# My code runs fine the first time I run it but when running it again it returns this error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. Why?

Tags: python, netcdf, nonetype

So I am trying to make a plot from netCDF data using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import netCDF4 as nc
from netCDF import Dataset
import numpy as np

def av_mrsoMF(t, path1, path2):
    # Inputting the data
    ds = nc.MFDataset([path1, path2])
    lat = ds.variables['lat'][:]
    lon = ds.variables['lon'][:]
    mrso = ds.variables['mrso'][t,:,:]

    # Restricting data to Europe
    mrso_zeros = np.zeros(np.shape(mrso))
    mrso_EU1 = mrso[62:83, 0:18]
    mrso_EU2 = mrso[62:83, 132:143]
    mrso_EU = np.concatenate((mrso_EU1, mrso_EU2), axis=1)

    # Taking an average over europe at time t
    return np.average(mrso_EU)

def plot_av_mrso(path1, path2):
    # Inputting the data
    ds = nc.MFDataset([path1, path2])
    lat = ds.variables['lat'][:]
    lon = ds.variables['lon'][:]
    time = ds.variables['time'][:]
    mrso = ds.variables['mrso'][:,:,:]

    # Restricting data to Europe
    mrso_zeros = np.zeros(np.shape(mrso))
    mrso_EU1 = mrso[62:83, 0:18]
    mrso_EU2 = mrso[62:83, 132:143]
    mrso_EU = np.concatenate((mrso_EU1, mrso_EU2), axis=1)
    
    # Create a zero matrix to store result in  
    average_mrso = np.zeros(np.size(time))

    # Create loop to find average at each time
    for i in range (np.size(time)):
        average_mrso[i] = av_mrsoMF(i, path1, path2)   
    
    # Plot Average mrso against time
    plt.plot(time, average_mrso)
    plt.xlabel('Time (year)')
    plt.ylabel('Average European Soil Moisture Content (kg/m^2)')
    plt.show()

plot_av_mrso(r1i1p1f1_hist_path2000, r1i1p1f1_hist_path2014)
```

It runs perfectly the first time, however if I try run it again it returns this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-9021b0e3c688> in <module>()
     42     plt.show()
     43 
---> 44 plot_av_mrso(r1i1p1f1_hist_path2000, r1i1p1f1_hist_path2014)

<ipython-input-44-9021b0e3c688> in plot_av_mrso(path1, path2)
     37 
     38     # Plot Average mrso against time
---> 39     plt.plot(time, average_mrso)
     40     plt.xlabel('Time (year)')
     41     plt.ylabel('Average European Soil Moisture Content (kg/m^2)')

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

for the line:

```
plt.plot(time, average_mrso)
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? It is very confusing that it only returns the error on the second run.

I have tried to attach the data files that I am using for this, however I cannot find a way to do this. Any ideas on how to would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly do you run it again? Do you run the entire script again from the command line? Or do you call the `plot_av_mrso` function twice (if so, please include the full code) ?

Comment: Also, can you please include the full stack trace of the error ?

Comment: I have now included the whole error message in the question - sorry for not having that in before. As for your first question, it is just when I run the entire script again from the command line.